# Java Generics Wildcard bounding cannot set

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes.

```
public class Basket<E> {
    private E element;

    public void setElement(E x) {
        element = x;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

class Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
class Orange extends Fruit {}
```

My confusion comes when I consider the following cases.

```
Basket<? extends Fruit> basket = new Basket<>(); 
basket.setElement(new Apple()); // cannot set
```

and

```
Basket<Fruit> basket = new Basket<>(); 
basket.setElement(new Apple()); // okay!
```

If `? extends Fruit` means that I can pass something that is at least a `Fruit` (or anything that implements or extends), why is it that I cannot pass in an `Apple` type? I cannot see any difference between the two cases if passing an `Apple` type in the second case works because `Apple` is a descendant of `Fruit`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Basket<? extends Fruit>` does not mean a basket that can hold any object as long as it is a subtype of `Fruit`. It means a basket of some unknown type `T` extending `Fruit`. For example it could be a `Basket<Apple>`, a `Basket<Orange>` or a `Basket<Fruit>`. Because it could be a `Basket<Orange>`, you can't set the item to be an `Apple`.

`Basket<Fruit>` is a basket of `Fruit`. Any fruit will do.

Comment: So because we have the possibility of passing in more than one type of fruit, Java disallows methods that contain `<E>` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes. E is unknown because you used a wildcard. Therefore the compiler disallows you from passing an Apple because E could be Orange.